# Как проверить наличие значения у ключа, а не индекса

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива:

```
$a1 = array('country' => array('Russia', 'Ukraine', 'Belarus'));
$a2 = array('country' => array('Russia' => 'Krasnodar', 'Ukraine' => 'Kiew', 'Belarus' => 'Minsk'));
```

Задача проверить, чтобы у значениея был задан ключ, а не индекс. Второй массив правильный, первый нет. Есть ли такая возможность или рыть куда-то в другую сторону?

UPD: Помог вариант из комментариев с проверкой is_string.

Comment: [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 2):

Использовать функцию `array_key_exists` или `isset`

```
if (array_key_exists('key', data))
  echo 'Exists';
if (isset(data['key']))
  echo 'Exists';
```

Только будьте внимательны, если ключ присутствует но имеет значение `NULL`, то `array_key_exists` вернет значение `true`, а `isset` - `false`

Comment: К сожалению проверка дает не тот результат.

Comment: Я в foreach делаю проверку на наличие значения у ключа. $array = array('country' => array('Russia', 'Ukraine', 'Belarus')); foreach($array as $key => $array) { if(isset($array[$key]) { echo 'yes'; } else { echo 'no'; } } выдает yes, а мне нужно чтобы yes было только если массив второго вида из шапки. Прошу прошение, что код не оформлен, пишу с телефона.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров Нет никакого смысла проверять `isset($array[$key])` внутри `foreach`. Т.к. цикл изначально пробегает только по существующим элементам. В данном случае у Вас `$key` будет равен 0, 1, 2...

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров Может, Вам использовать проверку `is_string($key)`?

Comment: вот, а мне нужно, чтобы ключ был только тем значением, что я задал. Не присваивая индексы и тем самым проходя проверку. Нужно, чтобы либо, как я задал array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2), а не array('first', 'second') либо выводило echo 'no'; Такое возможно?

Comment: Я попробую это, но чуть позже. Надеюсь поможет для решения моей задачи.

Comment: @ДмитрийГончаров Либо определите список валидных ключей и проверяйте по этому списку, либо используйте `is_string`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, использовать `array_key_exists`:

```
if (array_key_exists('Russia', $a1['country'])) {
  echo 'Россия имеет значения`;
} else echo 'Россия не имеет значений`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить является ли массив ассоциативным:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$is_assoc = array_keys($keys) !== $keys;
```